# How can i use reset button in form_tag rails4

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

```
 <%= form_tag do %>
  <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="input-field col s12">
              <%= text_field_tag :sid , params[:sid], :length => 9 %>
              <h6 class="grey-text" style="font-size: 1vw">Ex.570510XXX</h6>
          <%= label_tag(:sid, "Student ID") %>
      </div>

      <div class="input-field col s6">
           <%= text_field_tag :semester, params[:semester], :length => 1 %>
           <%= label_tag(:semester, "Semester") %>
           <h6 class="grey-text" style="font-size: 1vw">Ex.Term 2 = input 2</h6>
      </div>

       <div class="input-field col s6">
            <%= text_field_tag :year, params[:year], :length => 2 %>
           <%= label_tag(:year, "Year") %>
           <h6 class="grey-text" style="font-size: 1vw">Ex.2558 = input 58</h6>
      </div>

      <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

      <div class="col s6">
         <%= button_tag(value: 'Submit',class: "waves-effect waves-light btn right") do %>
            Submit
            <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
          <% end %>
      </div>

      <div class="col s6">
          <%= button_tag(value: 'CLEAR',type: 'reset',class: "waves-effect waves-light btn") do %>
            CLEAR
             <i class="material-icons right">delete</i>
          <% end %>
      </div>     
</div>
```

i want to a button_tag type=reset to clear every page

it's work when i'm reset before submit. if i'm press submit it's not working.

try my page : http://timetable4cmu.herokuapp.com/

input: StudentID = 570510629, Semester=2, year=58
when you input and submit clear button will not working.

please help me!!

Comment: I am using Google Chrome browse and it's work fine in here. Do you cross check on different browsers?

Comment: Do you press submit button yet?

Comment: So you want to clear the form after submit?

Comment: The clear button is working as expected after submit the form also, your problem here is you are passing params in the form fields. 

Just to verify the clear button is working or not, try this: Change any one of the field and click clear. It will replace the params(value which you have submitted first).

Comment: I have tried like this:
Submit the form with the values that you have given. And after submit I have changed the value of semester from 2 to 4. Then I have clicked the clear button. Then its revert to 2. So the reset is working but you are passing params in the form field that makes the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your form `reset` button is not working after submission, I think( not sure) because it can't reset the default value(after submitting you show the form with populated value). You can manually update form data using `js/jquery` ( make input text data `''` empty string)

```
function resetForm(){
  $('input[ name=sid]').val('');
  $('input[ name=semester]').val('');
  $('input[ name=year]').val('');

}
```

and call this method after with jquery

```
$('button[type=reset]').click(function(event){
 event.preventDefault();
 resetForm();
});
```

Comment: thank you very much. it's work. and i'm want to reset table, too. What should I do?

Comment: What do you mean by `reste table`? If you want to remove data simply can go back to starting page.

Comment: What will be the query if the field is select_tag/dropdown?

Comment: @AkshitThakurAk if you have any known value which you would like to select (Ex. `<option value="0">Please select</option>`), you can do `$('input[ name=my_select_tag_name]').val('0');` 
or to select the first options you can use 

```var dropDown = document.getElementById("my_select_tag_id") (you can use any other selector); 
dropDown.selectedIndex = 0;```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the parameters in the form after submit, then you should not pass the params in the form fields.

From this:

```
<%= text_field_tag :sid , params[:sid], :length => 9 %>
<%= text_field_tag :semester, params[:semester], :length => 1 %>
<%= text_field_tag :year, params[:year], :length => 2 %>
```

To:

```
 <%= text_field_tag :sid , '', :length => 9 %>
 <%= text_field_tag :semester, '', :length => 1 %>
 <%= text_field_tag :year, '', :length => 2 %>
```